# Appcelerator titanium - passing js variables

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, scope, titanium, appcelerator

I am new to JS and Appcelerator titanium. I am trying to implement the MVC model to my app, but I have a problem accessing the data in the model:

in the model.js:

```
var my_val;
```

then in file1.js, I modified the value of my_val:

```
Ti.include("model.js");
my_val=5;
```

then in another file file2.js:

```
Ti.include("model.js");
T.API.info(my_val); // the value I always get is "undefined"
```

why is file2.js not detecting the change file1.js has done to my_val? Is there anyway to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

take a look at my blog posting regarding this particular problem.

[blog.clearlyinnovative.com](http://bit.ly/mF12fj)

you want to include both files in your app.js and add the variable to your namespace; this is cleaner and doesn't pollute the global scope.

```
var myApp = {};
Ti.include("model.js");
Ti.include("file2.js");
```

in model.js do something like this

```
var myApp.model = {};
myApp.model.my_val = 100;
```

in file2.js do something like this; no need to incude model.js again, the value was set in your own namespace and is clearly defined

```
Ti.API.info(myApp.model.my_val);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get this functionality done use [Titanium Properties](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.2/Titanium.App.Properties-module) so that you can get/set your variable as per requirement.Do something like this in your app.js

```
// initialize your variable, you can update it as well with your custom value
Titanium.App.Properties.setInt('my_value', 0);
```

You can get this value any where you want like this:

```
var myValue = Titanium.App.Properties.getInt('my_value');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because what the statement

```
Ti.include('model.js');
```

does is to just sort of 'copy-paste' the code in your 'model.js' file into the other two files. All the variables in 'model.js' will be available to the file in which you included 'model.js'. But this only means that a **copy** of the variable my_val is made available to 'file2.js' not a variable that is common to all files that have the Ti.include('model.js') line!Including a file in another is pretty much the same as typing out the lines of the first file into the second but it in no way connects all files that include a common file!
So maybe instead of

```
Ti.include('model.js');
Ti.API.info(my_val);
```

you can this try this seeing as you have already included 'model.js' in 'file1.js??'

```
Ti.include('file1.js');
Ti.API.info(my_val);
```

OR you can always go with Muhammad Zeeshan's advice and check out Ti.App.Properties. Good Luck! :)